# What equation to compare protein isoforms in a Western Blot?

Tags: proteins, statistics, western-blot, data

The protein isoforms I am interested in comparing appear as distinct bands on the gel I have already run. I have an Excel sheet with optical density measurements I obtained using ImageJ; it looks something like this:

```
Lane    Iso1       Iso2       GAPDH
1       149.06     194.646    893.08
2       832.654    494.473    148.335
3       49.998     490.539    147.361
4       29.347     208.53     120.652
```

For the other proteins I've analyzed so far, I've been computing fold-change relative to my loading control, GAPDH, with the following equation:

```
Fold-Change = Log2(Protein/GAPDH)
```

I'm not sure how best to compare my isoforms to each other and considering the following two equations:

```
1. Fold-Change = Log2[(Iso2/GAPDH)/(Iso1/GAPDH)]

2. Fold-Change = Log2(Iso2/Iso1)/GAPDH
```

I've already computed both of these values for all my samples, graphed them and found that the resulting graphs look pretty different. **Which of the two equations do you think is a better way to compare the relative quantities of these proteins?**

Alternative equations are also welcome.

Comment: Are your lanes replicates ?

Comment: No: each lane was loaded with a different sample.

Comment: Now see, the problem here is that in the first equation your GAPDH normalization factor is lost. So finally there is no normalization.

Comment: Could you explain more fully how the normalization factor is lost?

Comment: Oh, now I see that dividing the numerator and denominator by the same value cancels that value's impact on the final answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion you should use this formula:

$$ \frac{\text{log}_2(\text{Iso}_1/\text{Iso}_2)}{\text{log}_2(\text{GAPDH})} $$

This will normalize the relative fold differences between the isoforms with the loading control- GAPDH.

Since both numerator and denominator are log transformed they are in comparable domains unlike the formula-2 that you mention in your question. This is just a modified formula-2.